# Ao dar insert do resultado de uma consulta,esta inserindo apenas a primeira linha

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, query, mysqli

Estou trazendo uma consulta de um banco e vou inserir em outro,esta rodando a questão e que só esta inserindo a primeira linha e não todos os resultados,veja meu script abaixo:

```
    <?php 

    $host="192.168.0.249";
    $port=3306;
    $socket="";
    $user="root";
    $password="";
    $dbname="db1";

    $conEmp = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $dbname, $port, $socket)
        or die ('Could not connect to the database server' . mysqli_connect_error());

    $query = "select store_key as Loja, d.name as Departamento, sum(quantity) as Qtde, sum(amount) as Venda, sum(cost) as Custo, sum(margin) as MargemBruta, pos_number as Caixa                 from accum_item  as i                 left join department as d on i.department_key = d.department_key     where store_key in (1,2,4,5)       and pos_number >0       and fiscal_date between cast('2016-09-20' as DATE)      and cast('2016-09-20' as DATE)       group by store_key, i.department_key,pos_number      order by i.department_key";

    if ($stmt = $conEmp->prepare($query)) {
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($Loja, $Departamento, $Qtde, $Venda, $Custo, $MargemBruta, $Caixa);
        while ($stmt->fetch()) {
         $v_loja   =  $Loja;
         $v_dep    =  $Departamento; 
         $v_qtde   =  $Qtde;
         $v_venda  =  $Venda; 
         $v_custo  =  $Custo;
         $v_margem =  $MargemBruta;
         $v_caixa  =  $Caixa;
         }
        $stmt->close();
    }

     $conEmp->close();


    $host="192.168.0.210";
    $port=3306;
    $socket="";
    $user="root";
    $password="";
    $dbname="db2";

    $conEmp2 = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $dbname, $port, $socket)
        or die ('Could not connect to the database server' . mysqli_connect_error());

    mysqli_query($conEmp2,"INSERT INTO importacao (imp_id,
                                                  imp_loja,
                                                  imp_dep,
                                                  imp_qtde,
                                                  imp_venda,
                                                  imp_custo,
                                                  imp_margem,
                                                  imp_cx) 
                                VALUES ('',
                                        '$v_loja',
                                        '$v_dep',
                                        '$v_qtde',
                                        '$v_venda',
                                        '$v_custo',
                                        '$v_margem',
                                        '$v_caixa')");
     $conEmp2 ->close();

 ?>
```

Comment: E por que é que você acha que esse código deveria inserir mais de uma linha, se você está executando um único insert com um set de VALUES apenas?

Comment: Por que declarar os atributos de conexão 2 vezes, se você já havia os declarado no começo do código?

Comment: @diegofm sao 2 servidores diferentes

Comment: @Bacco somente dois atributos que mudam.

Comment: @diegofm realmente em teoria ele poderia mudar só esses dois, o bom de separar é se for algo sujeito a reaproveitamento, pra não esquecer de mudar nada. Na verdade, nesse caso eu acho que é melhor por direto dentro da função, sem variável extra. Inclusive esse port e socket tão sobrando, já que estão com valor padrão podem ser omitidos.

Comment: @OtacioBarbosa da forma que estava fazendo você deve colocar o insert dentro do while. Não e o correto, mais funcionaria.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema básico do seu código é que você está dando apenas um INSERT com um set de valores.

Uma solução **precária** seria dar um insert a cada linha retornada do primeiro servidor:

```
<?php 
   $host="192.168.0.249";
   $port=3306;
   $socket="";
   $user="root";
   $password="";
   $dbname="db1";

   $conEmp = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $dbname, $port, $socket)
      or die ('Could not connect to the database server' . mysqli_connect_error());

   $host="192.168.0.210";
   $port=3306;
   $socket="";
   $user="root";
   $password="";
   $dbname="db2";

   $conEmp2 = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $dbname, $port, $socket)
      or die ('Could not connect to the database server' . mysqli_connect_error());

   $query = "select store_key as Loja, d.name as Departamento, sum(quantity) as Qtde, sum(amount) as Venda, sum(cost) as Custo, sum(margin) as MargemBruta, pos_number as Caixa                 from accum_item  as i                 left join department as d on i.department_key = d.department_key     where store_key in (1,2,4,5)       and pos_number >0       and fiscal_date between cast('2016-09-20' as DATE)      and cast('2016-09-20' as DATE)       group by store_key, i.department_key,pos_number      order by i.department_key";

   if ($stmt = $conEmp->prepare($query)) {
      $stmt->execute();
      $stmt->bind_result($Loja, $Departamento, $Qtde, $Venda, $Custo, $MargemBruta, $Caixa);
      while ($stmt->fetch()) {
         mysqli_query($conEmp2,"INSERT INTO importacao (imp_id,
            imp_loja,
            imp_dep,
            imp_qtde,
            imp_venda,
            imp_custo,
            imp_margem,
            imp_cx) 
            VALUES ('',
            '$Loja',
            '$Departamento',
            '$Qtde',
            '$Venda',
            '$Custo',
            '$MargemBruta',
            '$Caixa')"
         );
      }
      $stmt->close();
   }
   $conEmp->close();
   $conEmp2 ->close();
?>
```

Agora, a solução mais adequada neste caso seria usar *prepared statements* na inserção também, o que agilizaria absurdamente a operação toda, mantendo apenas 2 *queries* e fazendo execuções seguidas (da mesma forma que está recuperando as linhas).

Comment: Deu certo,agora vou ler sobre prepared statements, obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: @OtácioBarbosa é a mesma lógica do SELECT que você fez. basta dar um bind nas variáveis, e no WHILE só vai dando os STEPS do insert

Comment: Ok,vou testar. Obrigado novamente.

Answer (score 1):

Simples: está inserindo apenas o seu último resultado.

Primeiro você faz um select e faz fetch nos resultados na linha

```
 while ($stmt->fetch())
```

Nisso, suas variáveis $v vão assumindo valores conforme o loop se desenrola.

Depois você insere os valores das variáveis no seu select do outro banco.

Duas coisas que você pode fazer:

1° colocar a sua query de inserção dentro do while no qual está fazendo fetch
2° guardar as informações do fetch em um array e depois inserir as informações deste array no insert (foreach)